# web-component-tester progress has incorrect total

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

The progress ring widget that appears at the top right-hand corner of the page when running web-component-tester seems to show the total number of tests as always 3x the number of test suites, rather than the actual total of tests.

Is this a known issue, or this there something that I can do to get the correct total to show?

As an example, in this screenshot I have only one test in my suite, yet when the test is finished, the progress ring shows only 33% completion:

[image]

I can see in the code for the [MultiReporter constructor](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/008f52b39c719f904ebc9be47e9f786339ae516e/browser/reporters/multi.js#L58) that `ESTIMATED_TESTS_PER_SUITE` is set to 3 and is multiplied by the number of test suites in order to compute the total [used by the Mocha HTML Reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/58e94445beb722372589cbd2a0372bf741e7f0b7/lib/reporters/html.js#L139-L142) to render the progress widget. It appears that the [onRunnerStart](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/008f52b39c719f904ebc9be47e9f786339ae516e/browser/reporters/multi.js#L231-L234) handler in MultiReporter is supposed to replace the estimate for the current suite with the actual total, but in my testing the `runner` argument passed to this handler is itself a `MultiReporter` object with an estimated total, so the updated total is still an estimate rather than the actual total.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out why the MultiReporter never computes the correct total, nor have I been able to find any hooks for explicitly specifying the total number of tests.